# error while issuing ID in hyperledger composer palyground

Tags: acl, hyperledger-composer

I am getting below error while issuing ID in hyperledger composer playground

**: Participant 'org.acme.pdrug.Doctor#d2' does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#emptydrug@0.0.1'**

Please provide solution

**Below is the ACL i've used**

rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule participantRule {
    description: "can perform CREATE & UPDATE operations for Transation PublishPrescription"
    participant: "org.acme.pdrug.Doctor"
    operation: CREATE ,UPDATE
    resource: "org.acme.pdrug.PublishPrescription"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule participantRule2 {
    description: "can perform UPDATE operations , IF the participant is owner of the asset"
    participant(m): "org.acme.pdrug.Doctor"
    operation: READ,UPDATE
    resource(v): "org.acme.pdrug.pdaccount"
    condition: (v.owner.getIdentifier() == m.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

rule Insurerrule {
    description: "Allow the all access to insurer"
    participant: "org.acme.pdrug.Insurer"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.acme.pdrug.*"
    action: ALLOW
}

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, I try to ping the network after deploy

```
composer network ping -n tignetwork -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s adminpw

Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error 
(status: 500, message: Error: Participant 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#PeerAdmin' 
does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#tignetwork@0.1.2')
Command failed
```

And ACL

```
rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Some solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Network and System ACL rule for the Participant to be able to do network operations.

```
rule NetworkControlPermission {
  description:  "NetworkControl can access network commands"
  participant: "org.acme.pdrug.Doctor"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
  action: ALLOW
}
```